# Extremal of functionals

Tags: differential-geometry, calculus-of-variations

By a functional we mean a mapping from some space of curves to $\mathbb{R}$. A functional can have infinitely many extremals or none. If $F$ is the length of curve connecting the north and south pole of some 3D ball, then $F$ has infinitely many extremals. I can't find an example where some functional $F$ has no extremal.

Comment: Of course you know examples of functionals with no extremals. Consider $-x^2$ on the reals. This functional has infimum $-\infty $. So it cannot have a minimizer. On the other hand consider the functional $I (x) = x^2$ for $x \neq 0 $ and $I (x) = 1$ for $x=0. $ This functional has non infinite infimum,  but no minimizer.

Comment: I am not sure that if $I$ is a functional. As far as I know, a functional is a mapping from a space of curves to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Oh maybe you should add some context,  because a functional in COV can be any real valued function. The domain is not important (though most of the time you use Banach spaces).

Answer (score 1):

Consider the space $C([0,1]; \mathbb{R})$ of continuous curves on the real line. Consider the functional: $$I(x) = \begin{cases} ||x||_{\infty} \text{ for } x \neq 0 \\ 1 \text{ for } x = 0\end{cases}$$

This functional has no minimizer and no maximizer. The notable things are:

- this functional has a finite infimum.
- this functional has a infimizing converging sequence, but the point of convergence is not a minimizer. This is because of lack of lower semicontinuity.

Comment: This one is simpler. Let $n$ be an integer and $f_n:[0,\pi]\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function such that $f_n(x)=n\sin x$. Define $X=\{f_n:n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$. If $F$ is a functional which maps $f\in X$ to $f(\pi/2)$ then $F$ has no extremal.

Comment: Yes, any linear functional does not have a minimizer.